# Modifying part of a string in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, string

I have a file named `variables.f90` , having many lines defining different variables, as follows ::

```
integer::n_monomer=6800
real*8::rx=5.0d0
#... randomly integer and real numbers defined
real*8::mu_nano=8.0d0
.......
......
```

and I dont know what will be the value of `mu_nano`, it can be any real number.
Now I want to modify the above statement such that, its value is incremented by 1 using bash script as follows ::

```
real*8::mu_nano=9.0d0
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like `fortran` code, and it is not the greatest idea ever to parse higher language source code, but anyway... with `awk`:

```
awk -F'[=.]' '/nano/{$2++; print $1"="$2"."$3; next}1'
```

This assumes that variable is always given with a dot. It takes only integer part of it (between `=` and `.`), increase by 1, and prints everything back.

Answer (score 2):

To edit in place, I'd use perl:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(?<=mu_nano=)([\d.]+)/ sprintf "%.1f", $1+1 /e' variables.f90
```